# What wattage should I use for a switching adapter?

Tags: watts

I have a bad switching adapter. It has a DC output of 14.5V 2.48A Max. I can't find a match anywhere. I think a 3.0 Max will work, but I don't know the wattage. The replacements I've found are 29W, 45W and 60W. Does anyone know which one would work without damaging my device? It's for a Brookstone Smart Projector.

Comment: \$P = VI\$ or \$ P/V = I \$. You must keep the voltage the same so you can simply divide by the current to find the wattage. Anything with more than the required current should suffice. Manufacturers tend to recommend their own adapters however as they can guarantee that the supply's performance will work for the device.

Answer (score 1):

You calculate the wattage by the formula $$ P = VI $$ where \$ P \$ is power (watts), \$ V \$ is voltage (volts) and \$ I \$ is current (amperes / amps).

Your original supply was 14.5 V x 2.5 A = 36 W.

Either the 45 W or 60 W replacements should be adequate.